# Why would NSWindowController return nil-value window property?

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit

I'm using modal sheets (slide down from top) to get user input. I currently have 2 that I think are identical except for the UI, each a NIB + NSWindowController-subclass pair. One works as expected, binding input to an array controller and table view. When trying to use the other, the `window` property of the NSWindowController is `nil`.

This code works:

```
      @IBAction func addItemButtonClicked(_ button: NSButton) {
      let window = document?.windowForSheet
      let windowController = NewItemSheetController()
      windowController.typeChoices = newItemSheetTypeChoices
      windowController.windowTitle = newItemSheetTitle

      print(#function, windowController.window) // output below
      window?.beginSheet(windowController.window!, completionHandler: { response in
         // The sheet has finished. Did user click OK?
         if response == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
            let structure = (self.newItemSheetController?.structure)!
            self.document?.dataSource.structures.append(structure)
         }
         // All done with window controller.
         self.newItemSheetController = nil

      })
      newItemSheetController = windowController
   }
```

The output of the print statement: *"addItemButtonClicked(_:) Optional()"*

This code doesn't:

```
   @IBAction func addItemButtonClicked(_ button: NSButton) {
      let window = document?.windowForSheet
      let windowController = NewRecurrenceItemSheetController()
      windowController.windowTitle = newItemSheetTitle

      print(#function, windowController.window)
      window?.beginSheet(windowController.window!, completionHandler: { response in
         // The sheet has finished. Did user click OK?
         if response == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
            let recurrence = (self.newItemSheetController?.recurrence)!
            self.document?.dataSource.recurrences.append(recurrence)
         }
         // All done with window controller.
         self.newItemSheetController = nil

      })
      newItemSheetController = windowController
   }
```

The output of the print statement: *"addItemButtonClicked(_:) nil"*

Classes `NewItemSheetController` and `NewRecurrenceItemSheetController` are subclasses of NSWindowController and differ only with NSNib.Name and properties related to differing UI. As far as I can see, the XIBs and Buttons are "wired" similarly. The XIBs use corresponding File's Owner. Window objects have default class.

```
@objcMembers
class NewItemSheetController: NSWindowController {

   /// other properties here

   dynamic var windowTitle: String = "Add New Item"

   override var windowNibName: NSNib.Name? {
      return NSNib.Name(stringLiteral: "NewItemSheetController")
   }

   override func windowDidLoad() {
      super.windowDidLoad()
      titleLabel.stringValue = windowTitle
   }

   // MARK: - Outlets

   @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: NSTextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var typeChooser: NSPopUpButton!


   // MARK: - Actions

   @IBAction func okayButtonClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
      window?.endEditing(for: nil)
      dismiss(with: NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK)
   }

   @IBAction func cancelButtonClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
      dismiss(with: NSApplication.ModalResponse.cancel)
   }

   func dismiss(with response: NSApplication.ModalResponse) {
      window?.sheetParent?.endSheet(window!, returnCode: response)
   }
}
```

Why does one return instantiate a windowController object with a nil-valued window property?

Comment: Is the `window` outlet connected in the xib?

Comment: Nope. It wasn't. Didn't have the delegate attached in IB either. Thanks! It's not easy learning AppKit in a UIKit world.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, the XIB Window needed to be attached to File's Owner with a Window outlet and delegate. Thanks @Willeke.